# Is there a way to use global variable at a certain point in my local function?

Tags: python-3.7

To understand my question, here is a sample piece of code with global keyword in use -

```
def span():
    global eggs
    eggs='Hello'
    print(eggs) # Prints 99


eggs=99
span()
```

Here is my experiment  -

```
def span():
    eggs='Hello'
    print(eggs)
    global eggs 
    print(eggs)

eggs=99
span()
```

which leads to an error -

> name eggs is used prior to declaration.

My intention is to come up with an approach to use global value at a certain point in my program, and the rest of the time the local variable maintains its value inside the function.

Please suggest an approach to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `globals()` which is a dict of global-variables (as opposed to `locals()`):

```
def span():
    eggs='Hello'
    print(eggs)
    eggs = globals()["eggs"]
    print(eggs)

eggs=99
span()

# Outputs:
# Hello
# 99
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your first code works fine :)

Look the fiddle:

https://repl.it/@WaskaChaduneli/Stackoverflow54529122

Comment: Yes sir, I am aware of that. What i want is a refinement to what I am trying to do in the next piece of code(Refer the code snippet I am experimenting).